# Create a list of generic interfaces with the classes, that implement the interrace

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following classes & interfaces:

`public interface IValueMapper<TData>{ }`

`public class MyMapper : IValueMapper<IMyType> { }`

`public class MyRecord : BaseType, IMyType`

I am trying to create the following list:

```
var mappers = new List<IValueMapper<MyRecord>>{new MyMapper() };
```

but I get Compiler Error CS1503.

Is there a way to create the list I want?

Comment: I don't have all the error codes memorized. Please include the meaning of `CS1503` so we don't all have to look it up

Comment: MyMapper is of type IValueMapper<IMyType> rather than type IValueMapper<MyRecord>

Comment: `var mappers = new List<IValueMapper<IMyType>> { new MyMapper() };`. CS1503 is a conversion error, its description should tell you what it cannot convert to

Comment: Your list only holds value mappers of <MyRecord>, but you're trying to insert a mapper that uses <IMyType>.

Change your list: `var mappers = new List<IValueMapper<IMyType>> { new MyMapper() };`

or change your MyMapper: `public class MyMapper : IValueMapper<MyRecord> { }`